# Building arduino smartwatch with ios

Tags: arduino

I want to build a smartwatch with arduino. I've Arduino Uno, HM-10 Bluetooth Module and oled display. I need to receive notifications, weather, time, date etc. simply things. My phone is not jailbroken rn but if it is necessary i can make it. Are there any up to date examples? Can anyone help me to make progress?

Comment: Literally google a library for each module you have and then use it. Also, smartwatches don't use Arduinos. If you haven't noticed, Arduinos are much bigger than any smartwatch. If you want a smartwatch that is comfortable to wear, you need to build your own CPU or a small computer that doesn't support software.

Comment: i'm just trying it on breadboard first. thats why i use arduino uno. It doesn't matter that its wearable for now. thank you for answering.

Answer (score 0):

I think this [Project](https://create.arduino.cc/projecthub/dspenas/smartwatch-arduino-led-control-10005e?ref=tag&ref_id=smartwatches&offset=1) at the Arduino Project Hub could be a good way to start and then build on top of it, if you want more functionalities.